# Confused on uninitialized local variable being used when initialized?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am getting an uninitialized Local variable error when I do believe I have already initialized. The error reads uninitialized local variable `wk1` being used (It's wk1-wk5).

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const double tax = 0.14;

int main()
{   

    int wk1,wk2,wk3,wk4,wk5;
    wk1,wk2,wk3,wk4,wk5 = 0;

    int thours = wk1 + wk2 + wk3 + wk4 + wk5; <------------ This is the error line.
    thours = 0;

    double payrate;
    payrate = 0;

    double gross = thours * payrate;
    double taxes = tax * gross;
    double net = gross - taxes;
    double clothes = 0.10 * net;
    double supplies = 0.10 * net;
    double remaining = net - clothes - supplies;
    double bonds = 0.25 * remaining;
    double pbonds = 0.50 * bonds;

    bonds = 0;
    gross = 0;
    net = 0;
    clothes = 0;
    supplies = 0;
    remaining = 0;

    cout << "Please enter the payrate for employee." << endl;
    cin >> payrate;
    payrate = 0;

cout << "Please enter employee's total hours for week one:" << endl;
cin >> wk1;
wk1 = 0;

    cout << "Please enter employee's total hours for week two:" << endl;
    cin >> wk2;
    wk2 = 0;

    cout << "Please enter employee's total hours for week three:" << endl;
    cin >> wk3;
    wk3 = 0;

    cout << "Please enter employee's total hours for week four:" << endl;
    cin >> wk4;
    wk4 = 0;

    cout << "Please enter employee's total hours for week five:" << endl;
    cin >> wk5;
    wk5 = 0;

    cout << "Here is income before taxes: " << gross << endl;
    cout << "Here is income after taxes: " << net << endl;
    cout << "Here is clothes and accesories: " << clothes << endl;
    cout << "Here is School supplies: " << supplies << endl;
    cout << "Here is personal bonds: " << bonds << endl;
    cout << "Here is parents bonds: " << pbonds << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
wk1,wk2,wk3,wk4,wk5 = 0;
```

This line is a comma operator expression, which is equivalent to:

```
wk5 = 0;
```

Because expressions like `wk1` has no side effect. Only the variable `wk5` has been assigned a value, the other variables are still uninitialized. You can do:

```
wk1 = wk2 = wk3 = wk4 = wk5 = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed my problem, but now i am getting a 0 for all my outputted calculations. Do you see anything that could be efficiently done to get values?

Comment: @user3312523 Statements like `double gross = thours * payrate;` won't bind the value of the variables forever. You need to calculate the value of `gross` **after** you got the valid value of `thours` and payrates`.

Comment: @user3312523: After every `cin>>` call you reset that variable to zero. Just remove those calls. An example: in your code `cin>>wk1; wk1=0;` remove the last line ( `wk1=0;` ) and things should be fine. Best regards.

Comment: Okay @Yu Hao, i am not understanding what you mean exactly on calculating it after i get those values. As that's what i am doing by multiplying payrate by thours.

Comment: I am still getting a 0 for all my calculations when i removed the cin>> wk1=0; and the others.

Comment: @user3312523 e.g: `a = b + c;`, this assigns the sum of the **current** values of `b` and `c` to `a`. But later, `b` and `c` has newer values, `a` won't update its value automatically, it stays the same unless you assign `a` with a new value.

Comment: Okay so when i input the employees pay rate 11.11 then the 22 hours for each week that gives the gross 1222.1, but instead i'm getting a 0 still. I'm not sure what exactly i have to change it. The math works out on my algorithm sheet. Thanks for you help! I know it may be a pain in the neck and the answer is simple, but im trying to understand what you mean.

Comment: @user3312523 Did you still set `payrate = 0;` after `std::cin<<payrate;` ? Initialize the variable when defining them, but setting them to `0` after getting some value from input, that doesn't make sense. I'm sure your current program is much different than the one in the question. Ask a new question about that because this question is focused on the compilation error.

Comment: i deleted that, and Yea its different i will ask a new question.